# dealing with ghost spaces command line php

Tags: php, command-line

I have a problem when I try to execute the following command line instruction with php exec:

```
    $instruction="mpirun -n 2 raxmlHPC-MPI ­-s ".$uploadfile." ­-p 12345 ­-m PROTGAMMAAUTO --­­auto­-prot=".$_POST["selectCriteria"]." ­-n outfile -# 2";
exec($instruction);
```

I print the variable what I want to execute and it brings with some spaces:

```
mpirun -n 2 raxmlHPC-MPI  ­-s /home/compartido1/workspace/raxml/uploaded_files/user_1449959556Alignment.fasta  ­-p 12345 ­ -m PROTGAMMAAUTO --­­ auto­ -prot=aicc  ­-n outfile -# 2
```

I don't know what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure were the additional spaces could come from. Its strange.

Beware of using data from `$_POST` directly and unescaped.

Please escape it properly using 
[escapeshellcmd()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php).

I've rewritten the command using string concatenation to build the command.

Maybe this solves the problem. Please give it a try.

```
$command = 'mpirun';
$command .= ' -n 2 raxmlHPC-MPI';
$command .= ' ­-s ' . $uploadfile;
$command .= ' -p 12345';
$command .= ' ­-m PROTGAMMAAUTO';
$command .= ' --­­auto­-prot=' . $_POST['selectCriteria'];
$command .= ' ­-n outfile';
$command .= ' -# 2';

$escaped_command = escapeshellcmd($command);

exec($escaped_command);
```

Comment: it's near the solution, but it puts a "\" on the end of $workD  in the first part of command, this is the complete command line:    $command = 'cd '.$workD.';';
   $command .= '/usr/local/openmpi-1.6.4/bin/mpirun';
   $command .= ' -n 2 raxmlHPC-MPI';
   $command .= ' ­-s ' . $uploadfile;
   $command .= ' -p 12345';
   $command .= ' ­-m PROTGAMMAAUTO';
   $command .= ' --­­auto­-prot=' . $_POST['selectCriteria'];
   $command .= ' ­-n outfile';
   $command .= ' -# 2';

Comment: I did it, thanks a lot!

Comment: Space missing in front of the slash. Glad i could help. Happy hacking :)